# Subsetting matrices: save 'unused' information

Tags: r, matrix, extract

I have a matrix `A` from which I extract information that is saved in matrix `B`.

```
A <- matrix(c(1:25),nrow=5,ncol=5)
A
B <- A[-c(1:2),]
B
```

How can I generate a matrix `A_red` that contains the first two rows of `A` (the information that is *not* stored in `B`). I can't (manually) specify the rows that are not extracted. I'd need an alternative to `A_red <- A[c(1:2),]`.

Comment: Do you only subset rows of `A` or also columns?

Comment: I only subset rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you subset `A` only by row and have not duplicated data per row you can try:

```
A[!duplicated(rbind(B, A))[-1:-nrow(B)],]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
#[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Can I use this structure for several matrices `B`,`C`,`D`?
I can of course use the command several times.

Comment: Yes you can use it several times or `rbind` all of them before the original and then remove the results of the extracted to subset the original.